# is there a way to use the interactive `cabal init` from stack

Tags: haskell-stack

Let's say I have a folder with some `.hs` files and I want to wrap it in a *project*

If I have `cabal install` and `stack` it's no big deal:

- use `cabal init` (interactive choosing stuff)
- go on with `stack init`

but when I just go the easy - just install `stack` route I don't have `cabal install` available - only `stack`

Now `stack init` does not work without a `.cabal` (or `.package`) file and for `stack new` I know of no template that does not set up additional files/folders.

**Probably** I'm missing something obvious and there is a `stack` parameter/command for this?

**If not**: What's the proper way to handle this? Install `cabal-install`?

Comment: I'm not aware of a `stack` command similar to `cabal init`. Either install `cabal-install`, then `cabal init` and `stack init`, or `stack new` and move the files into the fresh project.

Comment: yes that's what I thought ... to you think I should oben a issue with a request for this feature (not sure if many will find it useful)

Comment: actually just installing `cabal-install` via stack will not work as the `cabal` executable is dependent on a certain GHC and it will not find it in that env. ... well `stack new` here we go

Comment: Sure, you can open a feature request. It may not be implemented right away but others who look for the same thing can then give their `+1`s and it may turn out that more people than expected would find it useful.

Comment: Regarding `cabal init`, you can run `stack exec -- cabal init` to run `cabal` in `stack`'s GHC environment.

Comment: I thought so too - but it will not work with `stack exec -- cabal init` cannot reproduce right now (wrong system) but you'll get some error - but thank you for your time - if you add it as an answer I'll mark it

Comment: `stack exec --no-ghc-package-path -- cabal init` should work.

Comment: @sjakobi indeed it does - thank you! - can you turn this into an answer?